# GeoServer GetFeatureInfo Results Format - Without Geometries

Tags: geoserver, getfeatureinfo

In GeoServer, is there a way to only retrieve the attributes/properties of features, without geometries, using the `GetFeatureInfo` request?

I need to use the `GetFeatureInfo` request to retrieve features' attributes at a location when user clicks on a web map (similar to "Identify" tool in Esri). However, the response contains huge amount of coordinates/geometries in GeoJSON format, which makes it take up lots of computing/network resources. For example, some routes/lines geometries take up 10K lines when formatted nicely!

Looks like there is something called [Freemarker](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/geojson.html) but I can't find any good examples/resources so far. It appears that one limitation of Freemarker templates is it would apply to ALL `GetFeatureInfo` responses, whereas I only want the remove geometries for this particular web app.

Also we could use HTML or text format but they are harder to parse.

I'm new to GeoServer and we use PostgreSQL as the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: turns out there is a vendor parameter called [propertyName](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#propertyname) you can use to exclude geometry, by explicitly listing all the attributes you want.

For example, this URL will return the geometry which are quite a few coordinates:

```
https://data.stategrowth.tas.gov.au/geoserver/ssg/ows/?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&info_format=application/json&xsl_template=infoTemplate.xsl&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&STYLES=&VERSION=&version=1.3.0&LAYERS=GEO_ROAD_WORKS&WIDTH=1012&HEIGHT=858&SRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=16417092.979047688,-5189935.42838609,16494447.25167218,-5124352.458117498&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&QUERY_LAYERS=GEO_ROAD_WORKS&FEATURE_COUNT=25&X=510&Y=539
```

Using the `propertyName` parameter removes the geometry but still including the properties/attributes (just 4 of them in the example below):

```
https://data.stategrowth.tas.gov.au/geoserver/ssg/ows/?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&info_format=application/json&xsl_template=infoTemplate.xsl&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&STYLES=&VERSION=&version=1.3.0&LAYERS=GEO_ROAD_WORKS&WIDTH=1012&HEIGHT=858&SRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=16417092.979047688,-5189935.42838609,16494447.25167218,-5124352.458117498&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&QUERY_LAYERS=GEO_ROAD_WORKS&FEATURE_COUNT=25&X=510&Y=539
&PROPERTYNAME=ID,EVENT_TYPE,ROAD_NAME,TRAFFIC_MANAGEMENT
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an example on the page you link to, all you need to do is remove the lines that print the geometry. (`<#--` starts a comment, `-->` ends it)

```
<#list features as feature>
{
 "content" : "this is the content",
 "type": "Feature",
 "id" : "${feature.fid}",
 <#list feature.attributes as attribute>
 <#if attribute.isGeometry>
 <#-- "geometry": ${geoJSON.geomToGeoJSON(attribute.rawValue)}, -->
 </#if>
 </#list>
 "properties": {
 <#list feature.attributes?filter(a -> !a.isGeometry) as attribute>
 "${attribute.name}": "${attribute.value}"
 <#if attribute_has_next>
 ,
 </#if>
 </#list>
 }
}
<#if feature_has_next>
,
</#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Freemarker templates more. Howerver one limitation seems to be the template is applied to all responses, whereas I only want to remove geometries for one web app (I have edited my question to reflect this).